# Mouse over stop to work

Tags: javascript, css

For some reason mouseover  stop to work.

Before, when I hover mouse over a small picture, I could see the big picture. But now when I mouseover - nothing change even so I've tried the different browsers.

I didn't change the code and there are all images.. but mouseover function stop to work. Though, some time ago my files became invisible in hosting because of the wrong  redirection to Wordpress side. Is it possible that this file became corrupted?

How to fix it?

thanks.

.......  as below in code for some open and closing  tr  tags

//code as below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled-1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('ed2.jpg','den1.jpg','dian1.jpg','den2.jpg','ol1.jpg','mikl1.jpg','ton2.jpg','m1.jpg')">
<center><!-- Save for Web Slices (Untitled-1) -->
<table id="Table_01" border="0" width="801" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="16"><img src="photo_over/bir_01.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="137" /></td>
<td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="137" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="11"><img src="photo_over/bir_02.jpg" alt="" width="71" height="863" /></td>
<td colspan="13"><img id="bigone" src="photo_over/bir.jpg" alt="" width="695" height="463" name="bigone" /></td>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><img src="photo_over/bir_04.jpg" alt="" width="34" height="506" /></td>
<td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="463" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="13"><img src="photo_over/bir_05.jpg" alt="" width="695" height="43" /></td>
<td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="43" /></td>
</tr>
...........................................................................................
<tr>
<td colspan="3" rowspan="2"><img src="photo_over/bir_13.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="65" /></td>
<td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="13" /></td>
</tr>

.....................................................................................
<tr>
<td rowspan="3"><img src="photo_over/bir_27.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="86" /></td>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="3"><img src="photo_over/bir_28.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="86" /></td>
<td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><img src="photo_over/bir_29.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="85" /></td>
<td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="6" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><img src="photo_over/bir_30.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="79" /></td>
<td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="79" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="photo_over/spacer.gif" alt="" width="71" height="1" /></td>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices --></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my file is getting corrupted on the host.
Even so there is the function:

onLoad="MM_preloadImages()

But there are no other functions as below:
onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('biggest_one','','small1',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"

Therefore, mouseover doesn't work. 
To make it works, need to restore those functions.